# Integration of manually installed python libs into the system?

Tags: python, linux

I have manually built `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` etc - without root privilages (I needed fresh `matplotlib`). All libs installed in the standard place:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7
```

Now when I'm trying to install anything related - `synaptic` suggest me to install all the libs system wide. Is there a way I can tell `synaptic` to use the locally installed libs?

I tried to link `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `/usr/lib/python2.7` - no help.

**Edit**:

If I clone a python package, and change the name in the setup.py to the name of the ubuntu package, and then build:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=rpm
```

and then convert it to deb with alien:

```
sudo alien -k my.rpm
```

and then install the deb:

```
sudo dpkg -i my.deb
```

then `synaptic` does recognise it as a package (remember I've tweaked the name in setup.py).

But I can't find a way to make synaptic aware of locally installed python libs.

Comment: Could you try to install the packages you want from the sources with `python setup.py install --user` or something like that instead of relying on a package manager ?

Comment: @PierreGM: That's exatcly what I've done! Have You read my question?

Comment: Looks like we're not understanding one another: I was suggesting to install 'anything related' yourself, from the sources, not using a package manager like `synaptic`.

Comment: @PierreGM: Oh - now I got You. Well it is also the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can a package manager, that manages packages at a *system level*, know anything about something that is installed in a user directory, something that is the opposite of the *system level*?

A package manager resolves dependencies based on meta-information stored in a package (be it rpm, deb, whatever) and/or package repository.

To achieve your goal you can go either of two options.

First is to build a system-specific package from your sources and then install it via your package manager. See [Creating Built Distributions](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.1/distutils/builtdist.html) docs for that. It would look something like this:

```
$ python setup.py bdist --format=rpm
$ rpm -i dist/$PACKAGE.rpm
```

That would make your package manager aware of the fact that some dependencies are already provided.

This approach may or may not work.

The other, preferred, option is to use python package manager such as [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) and install all your packages in a [virtual environment](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). There are several advantages of this method:

1. You can have several distinct package sets, with different versions of packages installed.
2. You can optionally isolate your virtual environment from the packages installed system-wide.

Comment: I can understand that generally it's not possible - but in case with python -- it can be done: python itself knows both my local packages and system wide ones.